# Number of distinct MSTs of a Grapth with non-distinct weights

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Consider below graph:

[image]

We can calculate the number of distinct MSTs as following,

We have three triangles, which are similar.

we can delete one side from 1st and 2nd triangles and two sides from 3rd triangle.

Total number of ways to delete sides to make a MST and number of distinct MSTs is

```
3P1 * 3P1 * 3P2 = 3 * 3 3 * 6 = 54
```

This solution is very specific to this problem, how can we mathematically establish this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_theorem

Comment: Thanks @DavidEisenstat, Kirchhoff's Theorem works, and it needs rigorous matrix calculations, if one has to solve it manually.